# How to execute a powershell script, Active Directory, remotely

Tags: powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to execute a powershell script on a remote computer that has access to the Active Directory Module, and the Invoke-Command -ComputerName ... isn't working right. Do I have any other options?

What I would really like to be able to accomplish is query my AD using the Get-ADComputer and even the Remove-ADComputer.

UPDATE

Ok so This is my script

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$computer = 'mjdl736'

$filter = "(name="+$computer+")"

Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter $filter
```

and since on my local machine I don't have access to the ActiveDirectory module I would like to run this code on a computer that do have access. So I tried

```
Invoke-Command mjdl736 -FilePath 'C:\Test1.ps1'
```

Which mjdl736 does have access to ActiveDirectory and the Test1.ps1 is on my local machine

UPDATE 2

This is the error I get : Error initializing default drive: ‘Unable to find a default server with Active Directory Web Services running

Thank you

Comment: Post the actual code that you're running - what exactly are you doing, and what is the result/error? That way people can look it over and advise you as to how to fix it. "Isn't working right" is not enough information for anyone to help you.

Comment: I hope that my new update help you understand my problem a bit better.

Comment: "Isn't working right" isn't enough for people to help you. **What is the error message you get, if any**?

Comment: OK I've updated with my error message, plus I've been looking on the internet on the error message and got some info on it, so I'm trying some stuff to correct it.

Comment: Is the remote system joined to a domain? Does that domain have at least one DC with ADWS running? Can you point `Get-ADComputer` at a specific DC with the `-server` parameter?